# Singly linked list implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linked-list, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for feedback on my singly linked list implementation in JavaScript. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on coding style, documentation, bug fixes, etc.

**UML / code overview**

> ```
> LinkedList
>     _head - The first element in the list
>     _size - The number of elements in the list
>
>     getSize()
>         Returns the number of elements in the list
>
>     get(index)
>         Returns the node at index
>         Throws a ReferenceError if index is not specified
>         Throws a RangeError if index is out of range
>
>     getFirst()
>         Returns the first element in the list
>         Calls and returns this.get(0)
>
>     getLast()
>         Returns the last element in the list
>         Calls and returns this.get(this._size - 1)
>
>     add(node, index)
>         Inserts the given node at the specified index
>         Throws a ReferenceError if node is not passed
>         Throws a TypeError if node is not an instance of ListNode
>
>     addFirst(node)
>         Inserts the given node at the front of the list
>         Calls and returns add(node, 0)
>
>     addLast(node)
>         Appends the given node at the end of the list
>         Calls and returns add(node, this._size - 1)
>
>     remove(index)
>         Removes and returns the node at the specified index
>         Throws a ReferenceError if index is undefined
>         Throws a RangeError if index is not between 0 and this._size
>
>     removeFirst()
>         Removes and returns the first node in the list
>         Calls and returns remove(0)
>
>     removeLast()
>         Removes and returns the last node in the list
>         Calls and returns remove(0)
>
>     clear()
>         Removes all elements in the list
>
>     set(index, node)
>         Replaces the node at index with the given node
>         Calls this.remove(index) then calls and returns this.add(node, index)
>
>     indexOf(value)
>         Returns -1 or the first index value is found at
>         Throws a ReferenceError if value is undefined
>
>     lastIndexOf(value)
>         Returns -1 or the last index value is found at
>         Throws a ReferenceError if value is undefined
>
>     contains(value)
>         Returns true/false if the value is/not in the list
>
> ListNode
>     _value - The value this node holds
>     _next - The next node in the list
>
>     getValue()
>     setValue(value)
>
>
>     getNext()
>     setNext(node)
> ```

**Code**

I've left out the `ListNode` class because there's nothing more to it than the UML above.

```
class LinkedList {

  // Initializes the list by setting the head to null,
  // and the size to 0
  constructor() {
    this._head = null;
    this._size = 0;
  }


  // Returns the number of nodes in the list
  getSize() {
    return this._size;
  }


  // Returns the head of the list
  getFirst() {
    return this._head;
  }


  // Returns the tail of the list
  getLast() {
    return this.get(this._size - 1);
  }


  // Returns the node at the specified index
  get(index) {

    // If the index parameter was not specified
    if (index === undefined) {
      throw new ReferenceError('no index was specified', 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    // Make sure the index is in range
    if (index < 0 || index >= this._size) {
      const msg = `Index (${index}) out of range; List size (${this._size})`;
      throw new RangeError(msg, 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    let current = this._head;

    for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      current = current.getNext();
    }

    return current;
  }


  // Inserts the given node at the specified index
  add(node, index) {

    // If the node parameter was not specified
    if (node === undefined) {
      throw new ReferenceError('no node was specified', 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    // Make sure node is a ListNode
    if (!(node instanceof ListNode)) {
      const msg = "add(node, index): node must be of type ListNode";
      throw new TypeError(msg, 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    // The index parameter is optional. If not defined, add node to the end
    if (index === undefined) {
      index = this._size;
    }

    // Make sure the index is in range
    if (index < 0 || index > this._size) {
      const msg = `Index (${index}) out of range; List size (${this._size})`;
      throw new RangeError(msg, 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    // If inserting the node at the beginning of the list
    if (index === 0) {

      // Set the node's next to point to the current head
      node.setNext(this._head);

      // Replace the current head with the new node
      this._head = node;
      this._size++;

      return node;
    } else {

      // The node just before the insertion index
      let previous = this.get(index - 1);

      // The node at the insertion index
      let next = previous.getNext();

      // Set the node at the insertion index
      previous.setNext(node);
      node.setNext(next);

      this._size++;
      return node;
    }
  }


  // Inserts the given node at the beginning of the list
  addFirst(node) {
    return this.add(node, 0);
  }


  // Appends the given node at the beginning of the list
  addLast(node) {
    return this.add(node, this._size);
  }


  // Removes and returns the node at the specified index
  remove(index) {

    // If the index parameter was not specified
    if (index === undefined) {
      throw new ReferenceError('no index was specified', 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    // Make sure the index is in range
    if (index < 0 || index > this._size) {
      const msg = `Index (${index}) out of range; List size (${this._size})`;
      throw new RangeError(msg, 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    // If removing the head of the list
    if (index === 0) {
      const removed = this._head;

      this._head = this._head.getNext();
      this._size--;

      return removed;
    } else {

      // The node at the index before the one to be removed
      let previous = this.get(index - 1);

      // The node to be removed
      let removed = previous.getNext();

      // Removes the node at index by setting the next pointer of the node at
      // index-1 to the node at index+1, skipping the node at index
      previous.setNext(removed.getNext());
      this._size--;

      return removed;
    }
  }


  // Removes and returns the head of the list
  removeFirst() {
    return this.remove(0);
  }


  // Removes and returns the last node in the list
  removeLast() {
    return this.remove(this._size - 1);
  }


  // Empties the list by setting the head to null and sets the size to 0
  clear() {
    this._head = null;
    this._size = 0;
  }


  // Replaces the node at the specified index with the given node
  set(index, node) {

    // Remove the node currently at index
    this.remove(index);

    // Inserts the new node at the specified index
    return this.add(node, index);
  }


  // Returns the index that the value is found at, -1 if the value is not found
  indexOf(value) {

    // If the index parameter was not specified
    if (value === undefined) {
      throw new ReferenceError('no value was specified', 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    // If the list is empty, return -1 indicating the value wasn't found
    if (this._head == null) {
      return -1;
    }

    let current = this._head;
    let index = 0;

    while (current.getNext() != null) {
      if (current.getValue() === value) {
        return index;
      }

      current = current.getNext();
      index++;
    }

    return -1;
  }


  // Returns the last index the value is found at, -1 if it is not found
  lastIndexOf(value) {

    // If the index parameter was not specified
    if (value === undefined) {
      throw new ReferenceError('no value was specified', 'LinkedList.js');
    }

    // If the list is empty, return -1 indicating the value wasn't found
    if (this._head == null) {
      return -1;
    }

    let current = this._head;
    let lastMatch = -1;
    let index = 0;

    while (current != null) {

      // If a match is found, update the lastMatch to the current index
      if (current.getValue() === value) {
        lastMatch = index;
      }

      current = current.getNext();
      index++;
    }

    return lastMatch;
  }


  // Returns true if the value is in the list, false otherwise
  contains(value) {

    // Returns true if indexOf() finds the value, false if it does not
    return (this.indexOf(value) !== -1);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your if condition

```js
if (index === undefined) {
  throw RangeError('no index passed')
} else {
   // do the funk
}
```

by

```js
if (typeof(index) !== "undefined" && index !== null) {
  throw RangeError('no index passed')
} else {
  // do the funk
}
```

Because in your case you will have an error if you pass some `null` in your functions.

Comment: Would it be better to just do `if (index == null)` since that will be true if index is undefined *and* if index is null?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt try not to use `==` it is bad practice. It could be hard to debug when your codebase is going to grow ;)